# New databes tables with - WooCommerce - for developers

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I hope you are healthy and stronger than the virus. I am really interest to start coding WP and WC. I've been coding PHP for 2,5 years and started two weeks ago with WordPress. I'm reading the documentation a little bit and I'll continue with it, but I'm interested in how to get started programming woocommerce. How can i upgrade and develop it, and how can i create additional tables in the DB and integrate them. What can i develop more? I did not find some good tutorial. I am reading a doc. and code but it is complicate. If you can wright me some good tutorials or if you send me some links to buy good tutorials from Udemy. Thanks